# Adhering to size limit of a block

Tags: consensus, babe, inherent

We do track weight during block creation/block import, but weight only cares about execution time and with 2D weights also about storage proof size.

We do keep track of size in propose [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/657c808eb3d22284359a802d67fdfdbe823fbd17/client/basic-authorship/src/basic_authorship.rs#L452) but only for extrinsics. As far as I understand the code, we don't care about the size limits for inherents - we just assume they fit.

Now at least for parachain inherent data this is not necessarily the case. Candidates can be quite heavy, if there are lots of disputes and this can also be quite some amount of data.

If it is indeed the case that all other inherents have negligible size, then some size limiting within the parachains inherent could work. Still a bit fuzzy: What is the size limit, how much of it can we actually use (as other stuff will still have some size) ...

In any case this feels a bit unsatisfying, if we for example assume we can use 70% of the block size for parachain consensus and then another inherent assumes the same, we are already at 140%.

Ideally we would have something like this:

1. Inherents are ordered by priority
2. When asked for the inherent data, we get passed how much size is left to use.
3. We can use that size to determine what data to include and what to leave out.

Shall we add something like this or is there a better solution already available which I just missed?